# Can I test pre-registered user access without logging in as that user in Foundry?

Tags: palantir-foundry, palantir-foundry-security

In Palantir Foundry's Multipass, I created a pre-registered user to test data access based on specific markings. Is there a way to login as this test user? There's no password settings or similar.

I used the Edit policy > Test policy feature in a restricted view, but it doesn't appear to allow me to see the actual tabular preview of rows that my test user can view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, there isn’t a way to do this if you can’t login as them directly -- otherwise you’d be able to impersonate another user/view data with their permissions.